# Error BC30456 'Form' is not a member of 'Windows'

Tags: mysql, vb.net

```vb
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    With OpenFileDialog1
        .FileName = String.Empty
        .InitialDirectory = "C:\"
        .Title = "Open Excel File"
        .Filter = "Excel 97-2003|*.xls|Excel 2007|*.xlsx"
    End With
    Dim result As DialogResult = OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    If result = Windows.Form.DialogResult.OK Then
        Try
            TextBox1.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
            GetExcelSheetNames(TextBox1.Text)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error : " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Possible SQL injection. Use parameters to prevent this! Also it's important to disposed of your objects.

Comment: uh? what's your question and what's your problem?

Comment: gift me tips and trick for passing textbox form login to lable form 1

Answer (score 3):

```
Public Class Form1
    Private loginLabel As String

    Public Sub New(ByVal loginParameter As String)
         InitializeComponent()

         Me.loginLabel = loginParameter

    End Sub
End Class
```

and in your login form:

```
dim frm as new Form1(label.Text)
```